# What am I doing wrong when trying to use easygui.enterbox(...)?

Tags: python, python-import, easygui

I am three weeks into my independent study Python course, and am having trouble getting passed an issue. I am trying to use the function `enterbox()` from easygui I write:

```
import easygui
value = easygui.enterbox("say something")
```

And when I run it I get the error:

> **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'enterbox'

Does anyone know why this may be happening? Thanks! (I'm using version 2.7)

Comment: Is your own file named `easygui.py`, by any chance?

Comment: No it isn't. I tried saving it as easygui.py after reading your comment to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: I saw that there was one saved in the folder Python27, named "easygui.pyc"! So I deleted it, and now it works. I get my enterbox. Thanks!!!